# li active css bug in my case

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I think it's not bug, just that I'm no good in css. take a look why the border of active is different from the hover state:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mb398/1/

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Login In</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by different? Like the colors are not matching up?

Answer (score 1):

The .active is on the `<li>` but then in your CSS you set the :hover-styling on the `<a>`.

By removing "li a:hover" and replacing that with "li:hover" you'll get the right result.

[This is a fiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/Mb398/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting two different elements which have different dimensions.  The `.active` is the parent li which is slightly bigger than the `<a>` you are selecting with the `:hover`.  Since the li is larger, its border will be longer and slightly lower.  The `<a>` is also blue by default, so the border is blue.

**Solution**

*Step 1:*

You need to change each instance of

```
border: 5px solid;
```

to

```
border: 5px solid black;
```

This will fix the coloration issues.

*Step 2:*

Then change

```
.menu li.active {
```

to

```
.menu li.active a {
```

This will fix the size issues.

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pyPR/8/).